# Launch application to linux console on startup

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I have a small router without a keyboard and mouse, and I'd like to have it display network statistics using "jnettop" whenever the machine is booted up. How can I get the machine to display this information without requiring logging in and launching the application? The application jnettop requires root (I think) -- is this secure? If not, is there a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your router is running a Unix variant, like Linux or BSD, you can set up auto-login on tty1 and have the login script run jnettop (or anything else).  The details of setting up auto-login depend on the startup scripts used by your distribution, but take a look at the discussion of setting up a MythTV front-end for ideas: http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Frontend_Auto_Login

If this isn't clear I will try to flesh it out a bit, but hopefully it gets you started.